# CKeditor : Wrap ul list in a div with class

Tags: ckeditor

I wish to customize a new style in ckeditor (under liferay 6.2).
So far, I'm able to create styles like this, in the ckconfig.jsp :

```
{name: 'Floating style', element: 'div', attributes: {'class': 'floating-list'}}
```

This is a style I would like to apply to a wrapping `div` parent to a the desired `ul` list. It would look like that :

```
<div class="floating-list">
    <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But the problem is that when I apply the style to my list, it of course applies to my `ul li` contents like this :

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="floating-list">item</div></li>
    <li><div class="floating-list">item</div></li>
    <li><div class="floating-list">item</div></li>
    <li><div class="floating-list">item</div></li>
</ul>
```

To avoid this behaviour, I wrote a little piece of jquery code :

```
$('.floating-list').closest('ul').each(function(){
    var list = $(this);
    var item = list.find('li');
    item.each(function(){
        $(this).html( $(this).find('.floating-list').html() );
    });
    list.replaceWith('<div class="floating-list"><ul>'+list.html()+'</ul></div>');
});
```

This works actually, but this is really dirty.

I'm wondering if there was a way to make it out. Thanks.

Comment: I've got the same problem, but your jquery code, dirty or not, is very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but still ckeditor behaviour blows my brain up

Answer (score 1):

can try this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.idofyourCKEditor.on('change', function() {
    //for apply to all li's of ckeditor
    jQuery(".cke_reset").contents().find("li").each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).parent().is("ul")){
            jQuery(this).wrap("<div></div>"); //or .wrapInner( "<div class='new'></div>"); if you want do inside
        }
    });

});
```

with the event `change` can update the list when you are creating or editing

with the method `contents()` of jquery can update the elements inside of iframe `.cke_reset`, or the id if you can find him.

with the method `parent()` or `children().eq(0)` of jquery can get the element for check if is or not wrap

with the method `wrap("<div class='chimichanga'></div>")` and `wrapInner( "<div class='new'></div>")` can update the code html fast and easy.